# MySQL query to extract excess numbers mapped to an ID card after 10 counts

Tags: mysql

I'd trying to build a MySQL statement to achieve the following:

- Select IDs that have done more than 10 registrations.
- Delete any registrations done after the initial 10 counts in (a)

**Note:** This is a customer registration system.
Each ID should have only 10 registrations. Any ID that has more than 10 registrations, the statement should search and delete it when I run the query.

**Example:** There are 12 IDs below. The query should search the large DB and delete extra numbers from all such IDs.

```
DOCUMENT_ID             numbers 
 1. GLL-7189xxxxx-3     269842931   
 2. GLL-7189xxxxx-3     578954415   
 3. GLL-7189xxxxx-3     268017650   
 4. GLL-7189xxxxx-3     266503807   
 5. GLL-7189xxxxx-3     574609706   
 6. GLL-7189xxxxx-3     578952189   
 7. GLL-7189xxxxx-3     265839117   
 8. GLL-7189xxxxx-3     267228074   
 9. GLL-7189xxxxx-3     269220980   
10. GLL-7189xxxxx-3     571458667   
11. GLL-7189xxxxx-3     560273357   
12. GLL-7189xxxxx-3     560700857
```

Comment: Hi @Reuben, welcome to SO! You can achieve this using a `COUNT` function inside a `WHERE` statement, so try googling that first. If you run into any problems, edit your question to describe what you've tried so far. Good luck!

Comment: You say "initial" 10, how do you tell their order?

Comment: Using timestamp

TIMESTAMP
2022-03-02 12:01:20.0000000